# Ubuntu-userdel command or setting sudo priveleges (Python)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, sudo

Is it possible to set admin/sudo privileges or remove/add users through Python?
I'm not saying how to use a script as sudo (although I do also want to know that), but mainly how to set the privileges.

Comment: One option is to `sudo myscript.py`

Comment: You can also do os.system("gksudo somecommand") for any system running gnome or a minimal gnome form for commands that require super-user privileges.